# What does system type dependencies in gradle mean?

Tags: gradle

To convert a maven project to Gradle, I run `gradle init` on my project. The resultant `build.gradle` (snippet below) converted all local dependencies to `system` but there does not seem to be a lot of information on this kind of dependency online. Anyone familiar with these kinds of Gradle dependencies?

```
...
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-core', version:'1.3'
    compile group: 'org.restlet.jse', name: 'org.restlet', version:'2.3.7'
    compile group: 'org.restlet.jse', name: 'org.restlet.ext.jackson', version:'2.3.7'
    compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version:'2.7'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version:'1.10.19'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4', version:'1.6.5'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito', version:'1.6.5'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version:'4.11'
    system group: '...', name: '...', version:'1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    system group: '...', name: '...', version:'1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Comment: Does that script even works? Maybe, you've used `system` scope in Maven, and Gradle does not know how to map them, so it just created a new configuration, named `system`?

Comment: Yeah, that's probably it @madhead. I ended up having to add the git submodule dependencies by adding them in settings.gradle `include ":lib:<git_submodule_dir>"` and them referencing them in build.gradle `compile project(':lib:<git_submodule_dir>')`. Works fine now.